# Merging rows with same ID together with dynamic headers with CSV in java

Tags: java, arrays

Please Help, I just can't figure it out.

I am trying to merge CSV rows together that have the same ID number, but have different values in the fields.

Please i dont have code.

For example,

Read in this CSV file:

```
ID NAME PHONE EMAIL 
22 John 555-1111 john@aol.com 
22 John 555-2222 john@aol.com 
44 Bill 555-9999 Bill@aol.com
```

Should return:

```
ID NAME PHONE EMAIL PHONE0 
22 John 555-1111 john@aol.com 555-2222 
44 Bill 555-9999 Bill@aol.com
```

Thanks

Comment: you've got to give it a try and come back with what didn't work for you.

Comment: i want how i write a code for it

Comment: Have a look [here](https://coderanch.com/t/505601/java/Merging-rows-ID-dynamic-headers).